# Apply a command for each file in a folder using Windows batch script

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, ffmpeg

I am trying to figure out how to create a script that will take all video files in a folder videos\*.* and then use ffmpeg on each one and output the files to converted\*.mp4 where the filenames are the same.

However, I can't figure out how to get the `for` loop working, so that I can extract the name and extension type of file I am processing.

```
for %%f IN (videos\*.*) DO (convert.bat %%f)
```

convert.bat

```
ffmpeg.exe -i %1 -f mp4 converted\%~n.mp4
```

I have tried both with and without double quotes. However, it won't recognise the file.

Comment: Is there a typo on %~n.mp4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One liner batch file command:

```
for %%F in (videos\*.*) do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~fF" "%%~dpF\converted\%%~nF.mp4"
```

---

Two liner as you had it: (Added `call` command, quotations, and `~`)

```
for %%F IN (videos\*.*) DO (call convert.bat "%%~fF")
```

convert.bat (Corrected parameter usage with `~`, options, and quotations)

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "%~f1" "%~dp1\converted\%~n1.mp4"
```

---

See [`for /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), [`call /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732835%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) for help.